# Realm objects count right but properties of objects are default

Tags: swift, properties, realm

I have added an item in realm database but when I access the object , I saw that object's properties are wrong (default values).

```
class MyModel : Object{
    @objc dynamic var identityNumber = "00000000000"
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var country = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identityNumber"
    }
}

let model = MyModel()
model.identityNumber = "15644768124"
model.name = "ahmet vefa"
model.country = "Turkey"
db.addModel(model: model)

func addModel(model : MyModel) {
    try! database.write {
       database.add(model, update: true)
    }
}

database.objects(MyModel.self)
```

count is one but item's properties are default values ("00000","","") what is the problem here? I am using dynamic keyword.
note : swift version is 5.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the implementation of your `addModel` function.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: When I run that code, it's working. How are you verifying the model has the default values? Also what is this `database.objects(MyModel.self)` as it's incomplete. See  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I found problem.That does not show real values in debugging screen.Actually there is no problem.Thank you